# How do I fix an error in my python code where it is complaining about a string being wanted?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I was actually using code from a course at Udacity.com on Data Wrangling.  The code file is very short so I was able to copy what they did and I still get an error.  They use python 2.7.x.  The course is about a year old, so maybe something about the functions or modules in the 2.7 branch has changed.  I mean the code used by the instructors works.

I know that using the csv module or function would solve the issue but they want to demonstrate the use of a custom parse function.  In addition, they are using the enumerate function.  Here is the [link to the gist](https://gist.github.com/BruceMWhealton/f8181a2d003eaf14024c78b7ca53266f).

This should be very simple and basic and that is why it is frustrating me.  I know they are reading the file, which is a csv file, as binary, with the "rb" parameter to the line

```
with open("file.csv", "rb") as f:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have matching characters in your csv file and the dictionaries in your test function. In particular, in your csv file you are using an *em dash* (U+2014) and in your `firstline` and `tenthline` dictionaries you are using a *hyphen-minus* (U+002D).

```
hex(ord(d[0]['US Chart Position'].decode('utf-8')))
'0x2014'  # output: code point for the em dash character in csv file

hex(ord(firstline['US Chart Position']))
'0x2d'    # output: code point for hyphen-minus
```

To fix it, just copy and paste the `—` character from the csv in your gist into the dictionaries in your source code to replace the `-` characters.

Make sure to include this comment at the top of your file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

This will ensure that Python knows to expect non-ascii characters in the source code.

Alternatively, you could replace all the `—` (em dash) characters in the csv file with hyphens:

```
sed 's/—/-/g' beatles-diskography.csv > beatles-diskography2.csv
```

Then, remember to use the new file name in your source code.